# Too Many HTTP Requests from one source

Tags: apache-2.2, http, connection, wireshark, tripwire

We are having an issue at one of our customer sites where Tripwire is flagging events when more than 1000 HTTP connections are being individually created from different IP addresses within a span of one minute. We have turned on keep-alive( 10 secs) on our web server (Apache on Linux). We did some network capturing and noticed that while the keep-alive timeout is being honored, it may still be creating multiple connections for the requests.

[image]

Does anyone know why all these HTTP connections are being created? Any help will be appreciated.

EDITED: To avoid confusion

Comment: Talk with whomever is making the requests. If it's degrading performance, just block that IP.

Comment: if you want to ban him, you may use fail2ban and enable apache monitoring. TCP keepalive has nothing to do with mitigating new HTTP connections, why do you think this is a TCP issue?.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is different IPs are individually creating 1000+ connections within a span of a minute. I edited the original question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

without asking the originator of the requests its hard to 'guess' why they are being created, it could be a deliberate attack or the person might not be aware their system is making the requests.

As you're on Linux just add a block on the IP via iptables using the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -j DROP
```

Where x.x.x.x is the IP address of the user making the requests

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is different IPs are individually creating 1000+ connections within a span of a minute. I edited the original question to reflect that.